# Factorize using pandas on two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some data in a pandas dataframe that looks like this;

```
CAR_TYPE   MILEAGE
FORD       100     
FORD       100    
FORD       200    
FORD       300
VW         100     
VW         150
VW         150
VW         300
```

I want to 'factorize' the data to return a unique ID for each pair. However I want the unique ID to 'reset' to zero for seperate car makes. At present my factorization using the following;

```
df['CAR_ID']=pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.CAR_TYPE.values, df.MILEAGE.values]))[0] 
df.CAR_ID=df[['CAR_ID', 'CAR_TYPE']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

Gives me something like

```
CAR_TYPE   MILEAGE     CAR_ID  
FORD       100         FORD0
FORD       100         FORD0
FORD       200         FORD1
FORD       300         FORD2
VW         100         VW3
VW         150         VW4
VW         150         VW4
VW         300         VW5
```

Ideally I'd like

```
CAR_TYPE   MILEAGE     IDEAL_CAR_ID  
FORD       100         FORD0
FORD       100         FORD0
FORD       200         FORD1
FORD       300         FORD2
VW         100         VW0
VW         150         VW1
VW         150         VW1
VW         300         VW2
```

Apologies for the relatively dumb question, at wits after a long day. I know its something that could be solved with a stack/unstack, reset_index/set_index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html) if values in `MILEAGE` are sorted per group:

```
a = df.groupby(['CAR_TYPE'])['MILEAGE'].rank(method='dense') \
      .sub(1).astype(int).astype(str)
df['IDEAL_CAR_ID'] = df['CAR_TYPE'].add(a)
print (df)

  CAR_TYPE  MILEAGE IDEAL_CAR_ID
0     FORD      100        FORD0
1     FORD      100        FORD0
2     FORD      200        FORD1
3     FORD      300        FORD2
4       VW      100          VW0
5       VW      150          VW1
6       VW      150          VW1
7       VW      300          VW2
```

Another solution with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
a = df.groupby(['CAR_TYPE'])['MILEAGE'] \
       .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).astype(str)
df['IDEAL_CAR_ID'] = df['CAR_TYPE'].add(a)
print (df)
  CAR_TYPE  MILEAGE IDEAL_CAR_ID
0     FORD      100        FORD0
1     FORD      100        FORD0
2     FORD      200        FORD1
3     FORD      300        FORD2
4       VW      100          VW0
5       VW      150          VW1
6       VW      150          VW1
7       VW      300          VW2
```

---

Different outputs if column is not sorted:

```
print (df)
  CAR_TYPE  MILEAGE
0     FORD      500
1     FORD      500
2     FORD      200
3     FORD      300
4       VW      100
5       VW      150
6       VW      150
7       VW      300

a = df.groupby(['CAR_TYPE'])['MILEAGE'].rank(method='dense') \
      .sub(1).astype(int).astype(str)
df['IDEAL_CAR_ID'] = df['CAR_TYPE'].add(a)
print (df)
  CAR_TYPE  MILEAGE IDEAL_CAR_ID
0     FORD      500        FORD2
1     FORD      500        FORD2
2     FORD      200        FORD0
3     FORD      300        FORD1
4       VW      100          VW0
5       VW      150          VW1
6       VW      150          VW1
7       VW      300          VW2
```

---

```
a = df.groupby(['CAR_TYPE'])['MILEAGE'] \
       .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).astype(str)
df['IDEAL_CAR_ID'] = df['CAR_TYPE'].add(a)
print (df)
  CAR_TYPE  MILEAGE IDEAL_CAR_ID
0     FORD      500        FORD0
1     FORD      500        FORD0
2     FORD      200        FORD1
3     FORD      300        FORD2
4       VW      100          VW0
5       VW      150          VW1
6       VW      150          VW1
7       VW      300          VW2
```

Comment: This answer is nice ~ without the apply should be more efficient

Comment: Yes, but if need count per groups, then it is necessary with groupby.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! Most appreciated!

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Answer (score 4):

Or you can try this.

```
df['CAR_ID']=df.CAR_TYPE+df1.groupby('CAR_TYPE')['MILEAGE'].apply(lambda x:x.astype('category').cat.codes).astype(str)


Out[21]: 
  CAR_TYPE  MILEAGE CAR_ID 
0     FORD      100   FORD0
1     FORD      100   FORD0
2     FORD      200   FORD1
3     FORD      300   FORD2
4       VW      100     VW0
5       VW      150     VW1
6       VW      150     VW1
7       VW      300     VW2
```

Comment: Thanks Wen for your time and help!

Comment: @HamishRobertson glad it help ,nice day

Answer (score 4):

```
f1 = pd.factorize(list(zip(df.CAR_TYPE.values, df.MILEAGE.values)))[0]
f0 = pd.factorize(df.CAR_TYPE.values)[0] \
    * (df.groupby('CAR_TYPE').CAR_TYPE.transform('count').values - 1)

df.assign(CAR_ID=df.CAR_TYPE.add((f1 - f0).astype(str)))

  CAR_TYPE  MILEAGE CAR_ID
0     FORD      100  FORD0
1     FORD      100  FORD0
2     FORD      200  FORD1
3     FORD      300  FORD2
4       VW      100    VW0
5       VW      150    VW1
6       VW      150    VW1
7       VW      300    VW2
```

Comment: @jezrael fixed.

Comment: Way too complicated, but only performs `groupby` to perform `count`.  This was an attempt to be quick and short.  Oh, well... was fun trying (-:

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared for you time and help! Most appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This is also achievable by using [`groupby.ngroup()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html)  and convert to string using `.astype(str)` , then add it to `CAR_TYPE` column using [`series.radd()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.radd.html):

```
df['CAR_ID'] = (df.groupby(['CAR_TYPE','MILEAGE'],sort=False).ngroup()
                                    .astype(str).radd(df['CAR_TYPE']))
```

---

```
print(df)

  CAR_TYPE  MILEAGE CAR_ID
0     FORD      100  FORD0
1     FORD      100  FORD0
2     FORD      200  FORD1
3     FORD      300  FORD2
4       VW      100    VW3
5       VW      150    VW4
6       VW      150    VW4
7       VW      300    VW5
```

For more details , you can see what `ngroup` produces below:

```
print(df.groupby(['CAR_TYPE','MILEAGE'],sort=False).ngroup())

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    4
7    5
```